# Why receive FormatException on valid double input?

Tags: c#

I receive FormatException and I don't know why.

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
       at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
```

line of code:

```
DELTA_BUY = Convert.ToDouble(parameters["DELTA_BUY"]);
```

value (from debug window):

```
parameters["DELTA_BUY"] "0.0016"    string
```

**upd** works fine on one execution path but fails on another execution pass (when came from WCF). reproducable on double, works fine with strings. probably format/nationalization issue?

Comment: What about your regional settings?

Comment: @RubensFarias yes probably it's about that. but it's interesting that on one execution path it works fine. on another execution path it fails (updated description). I don't know where to check/adjust regional settings

Comment: Is it defiantly the same string in both paths?

Comment: @DaveShaw it's read from static file by the same code to read the file so I almost 99.99% sure that they are the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your machine perhaps set to a Culture where "0.0016" is not a valid number?
Try

```
DELTA_BUY = Convert.ToDouble(parameters["DELTA_BUY"], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hmmm... out of curiosity, what Culture is your machine on? English Cultures read that correctly and the continental European Cultures will read it as 16 (and not throw)...

Comment: I guess probably English or Russian culture because I have these two languages installed on the system.

Comment: Yeah, just tested parsing it with ru-RU and it throws.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're running on regional settings problems, due thread language or something related. If you always receive your data with `.` as decimal separator, you could go with this:

```
Convert.ToDouble("0.0016", new NumberFormatInfo{ NumberDecimalSeparator = "."});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the string itself contain double quotes? The parser would not be able to convert a string that had embedded quotation marks. Other than that, I see no reason why a string containing that value wouldn't be parsable as a double in the en-US culture or the invariant culture.

In other cultures, the decimal point may not be used to mark the "zero-power" place in the number. France (fr-FR) for example commonly uses a comma, and the thousands separator is a space. In any culture with these kinds of differences, attempting to parse this string would fail. You can avoid this by specifying a particular culture when performing the conversion, that you know will handle the number format being used:

```
//this will definitely work, as the en-US culture would definitely be able 
//to parse this number string.
DELTA_BUY = Convert.ToDouble(parameters["DELTA_BUY"], new CultureInfo("en-US"));
//this SHOULD work, and is generally more proper than forcing use of the US
//culture's formatter in a program otherwise designed to work in, say, Italy.
DELTA_BUY = Convert.ToDouble(parameters["DELTA_BUY"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The Invariant culture describes a generic English-speaking culture (which would use decimal points in fractional numbers), and should force the system to ignore any particular culture that may not use the decimal point to separate the whole and fractional portions of the number.

Comment: no, string itself doesn't contain double quotes, i think it's debugging window representation